# Link a custom entity with address entity in CRM Online 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

I have a custom entity that I want to link with Address entity. Custom entity has one address field for now but I want this entity to save addresses like Account or Contact entity saves the addresses in Address entity.

I tried creating a 1:N relationship but that didn't work. Is it possible guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Address entity is limited in that one cannot link other entities to it. In other words, there cannot be any relationships created other than what there is OOB.  **The Address entity is there for creation of addresses on Accounts and Contacts only.**
                       You can create a custom entity same as Address and then You can Use Created
Entity as a Entity Reference and Store Your  Information into CRM.